# Create npm script to run `tsc` and then something else, regardless of fail?

Tags: bash, npm, npm-scripts, tsc

So this is my setup in my package.json:

```
"scripts": {
   "build": "tsc",
   "test": "npm run build ; node --test ./dist/test"
},
```

I have heard in bash, instead of doing `&&` which won't run the second command if first fails, you can do `;` in between them, and I am trying to do this. However, the `tsc` command thinks `;` is a parameter and I get a `Could not resolve the path ';'` error.

BTW, when I say if first command fails, that's because `tsc` can output errors it finds to the log, but still compile the code into JS fine, so this is what I mean.

How can I achieve what I want?

EDIT:
Upon researching more, I found out it's due to me being on windows. I should use `&` instead to achieve the same effect. If someone is on a linux environment wouldn't this fail though, and how can I account for this?

Answer (score 0):

It wouldn't necessarily fail on Linux/Mac environment, the build and tests would just run in parallel. [npm-run-all](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-run-all) is a popular solution for this problem.

First, install it:

```bash
npm i -D npm-run-all
```

Then, configure your `package.json` with something along these lines:

```json
"scripts": {
  "build": "tsc",
  "rawtest": "node --test ./dist/test",
  "test": "run-s build rawtest"
}
```

Now, you have something cross platform that runs sequentially:

```bash
npm run test
```